# Sum of infinite positive numbers

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation

I have the following sum of infinite positive numbers $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k}^2$$ and I know that this sum converges, meaning that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_{k}^2 < \infty$$  The book I am studying  says that since the above sum converges, the following must be true $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}a_{k} = 0$$

I think that this is true because if I want the sum of infinite positive numbers to be finite, these positive terms have to be close or equal to $0$. However, I'm not sure why it takes the limit, because that implies that as $k$ goes to $\infty$ then the terms start to go close to $0$, correct? I know that the sum of positive numbers is finite then $a_{k}=0$ for all but at most countably many $k$, for which $a_{k}\neq0$.

So, first of all, are my above thoughts correct, and if yes, why does it take the limit and sets it equal to $0$ and doesn't just say that $a_{k}=0$ for all but at most countably many $k$?

Thanks in advance, sorry if my thoughts are a bit jumpled!

Comment: It doesn't have to be $a_k=0$ ever, i.e $a_n=\frac1n$.

Comment: As you only have a countable number of terms, says that $a_k = 0$ for all but countably many $k$ is useless.  Having $a_k$ *never* equal to $0$ is to have $a_k = 0$ in all be countably many.  (Countably many is the *only* thing you've got!)  Consider $a_k = \frac 1{2^k}$ so the $\sum a_k = 1$.  $a_k =0$ for *none* of the $a_k$ which is fine as zero *is* all but countlessly many.

Comment: @kingW3  If $a_k$ *never* equals $0$ then it is still true that $a_k =0$ for all but at most countably many $k$ because *all* $k$ are at most countable.  So *none* are "all but at most countably many".

Comment: @fleablood Indeed I assumed the OP meant finite instead of countable, but thought that pointing that pit might confuse the OP so I just gave the example which contradicts the finite statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider the partial sum

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_{k}^2 \to L$$

then

$$a_{n+1}^2=S_{n+1}-S_n \to L-L= 0 \implies a_n \to 0$$

Therefore the necessary condition for convergence is that $a_n$ tends to zero which doesn't imply that eventually $a_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it! Have a good day

Comment: @Thomas You are welcome! That's a basic but very important point for series.

Comment: Yeah looks important and basic, it's just that it's been a long time since I studied these :( I encountered the above in an optimization paper and was confused. Thanks !

Comment: I see what you mean now, wasn't clear to me last night. $a_{k}$ might never get to be actually $0$, but it's limit will eventually go to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity, correct?

Comment: @Thomas Yes exactly! That's te point. It can be actually zero but it isn't strictly needed.

Comment: True. Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing things up with sequences indexed by uncountable sets.

Only countably many terms may be non-zero for the series to converge (you have a typo here btw, it should read $\neq 0$), but this is only a necessary condition, not sufficient (think of the sequence of countably many $1$'s).

To see that $a_k$ must tend to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity, consider the difference of two consecutive partial sums (both of which converge to the sum of the series).

Comment: Yeah you are right, there is a typo, will fix it. Thanks for the help, didn't know it was a necessary condition ! Have a good day

Comment: Also, I think the edits I made are correct now, if not let me know !

Comment: "Only countably many terms may be non-zero for the series to converge"  It might be worth noting that "only countably many terms being non-zero" is *always* true of *all* series....

Comment: @fleablood well, not for any series of positive numbers indexed by an uncountable set. No matter how small such numbers are, their sum will diverge.

Comment: Ah... well, I wouldn't call something indexed by an uncountable set a "series".

Comment: @fleablood I mentioned this result because this was obviously what created confusion to the OP, given their question.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.  But it's important for the OP to realize that the result that $a_k = 0$ at all but at most countably many $k$, *IS* true but not relevant.  The text didn't ignore it, nor did the text come up with a case that it might not be true. And contrarywise that conclusion doesn't help us solve further.  Instead that result is, in actuality, trivial and vacuously true.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the sum of positive numbers is finite then ak=0 for all but at most countably many k, for which ak≠0.

You *only* have countably many $a_k$. It makes no sense to talk of for all but at most countable because *any* amount, even absolutely none or never, is "for all but at most countably many"... because the time it *does* happen (which is *always*) is only countably many.

Now surely you have come across $1 + \frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 18 + .... = 2$.

In this case $a_k = \frac 1{2^{k-1}}$ and $\sum a_k = 2$ and $a_k \ne 0$.

And it is true that $a_k =0$ for all but at most countably many $a_k$ because the $a_k$ where $a_k \ne 0$ are .... all of them... and all of them is at most countably many.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even in this case my statement is true though, right? The limit of $a_{k}$ will go to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity. It won't actually be $0$, but we can say that the limit is, don't we ?

Comment: Yes...The book says that and you say that.